is there a function to fetch date values in excel using office script that will preserve the format?
main program objective : skim through a column of dates and identify the row of current date
below code snippet objective: to print the cell value in date format
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook){
let sheet = workbook.getActiveworksheet("rainbow")  // rainbow is the sheet name
let range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10) // taking only 10 dates for checking
let values=range.getValues();

for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    console.log(values[i][0]) 

   }

}

The values of the column A are in the format:

when I expected the date to be printed as it is, the printed answers are
45495
45496
45497 etc
Can someone guide me where i am making mistake?
I tried searching in documentation but couldn;t find any function that can help me

Use range.getTexts() not range.getValues(), it will give you the value you see on screen, not the technical value behind the scenes.

Your script is using Excel's date serial numbers, so you need to convert these to proper date strings. Excel stores dates as serial numbers by default. Excel represents dates as serial numbers where January 1, 1900, is 1, January 2, 1900, is 2, and so on. For example, 45495 corresponds to July 20, 2024.
If you want to see those dates in a readable format, you need to convert those serial numbers to JavaScript Date objects. This is how you could do that:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("rainbow"); 
  let range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10");
  let values = range.getValues();

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    let excelDate = values[i][0];
    let jsDate = new Date((excelDate - 25569) * 86400 * 1000); // Convert Excel date to JavaScript date
    console.log(jsDate.toLocaleDateString()); // Print date in a readable format
  }
}

